# PHP - Simple HTML DOM Parser : content of <meta property=“og:description”

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to get the content of the meta tag "og:description" with the php code

```
if ($html->find('meta[property="og:description"]')!==null) 
{

    $post->excerpt = $html->find('meta[property="og:description"]')->content;   

} else {

  $post->excerpt = '';

}
```

The output is just:

```
["excerpt"]=> NULL
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: What does the find() method look like that you are calling?

Comment: What do you mean with that ? my find looks like this: find('meta[property="og:description"]')

Comment: I mean php doesn't have a find() function so whatever framework you are using (looks like Wordpress) has a find method that you are calling which I would like to see the logic for

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a 0 in there for the index:

```
$meta = $html->find($css, $index);
```

otherwise you get an array

Answer (score 1):

I would better parse the html just one time and yes, as pguardiario says, you need to add 0 for index. The code:

```
$metaOgDescription = $html->find('meta[property="og:description"]', 0);
if ($metaOgDescription !== null) 
{
    $post->excerpt = $metaOgDescription->content;   
} else {
    $post->excerpt = '';
}
```